# How to bold text in display name label of nonrequired control

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

Can somebody explain to me how to bold text in the display name label of a nonrequired control in Lightswitch.

Specifically I would like to know how to access the label of a control using code and change the style programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

Jewel Lambert has written a helper class on [her blog](http://dotnetlore.com/using-visualtreehelper-to-perform-lightswitch-wizardry/). The helper class can be used to change most of the visual elements of any Silverlight control. She gives a specific example of changing the label as that is a popular request.